# .Net 4 office automation without Visual Studio 2010

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, office-interop, sample

I am trying to learn the new dynamic keyword from .Net 4. After some basic examples I thought of trying the much touted easy office automation using .Net 4. But most of the links I could reach via google are using the VS 2010 IDE. As of now for business reasons I am stuck with VS 2008. But I have installed .net framework 4. Has any one written a office automation sample without using VS 2010. Can you point me to such a link?

Answer (score 1):

You can install Visual Studio 2008 and 2010 on the same machine.
So just install VS 2010 to play around with Office automation, and use VS 2008 for daily work.
(you can use the free [Express Editions](http://www.microsoft.com/express) if you don't have a full version of VS 2010)

Comment: I know that this is possible. As I said for business reasons I am not suppose to do this, not for technical reason.

Comment: Sorry, I interpreted "business reasons" as "we must use VS 2008 because we haven't upgraded our product to VS 2010 yet". You didn't clearly point out that you know it's possible to install both and are  just not allowed to do it.